# Is that possible to get the create time of the file when uploading file using asp.net FileUpload control

Tags: asp.net

When uploading file, is that possible to get the create time of the file when uploading file using asp.net FileUpload control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the creation time of the original file is not sent along in the upload.

To get the creation time you would need to run a component (Flash/Java/ActiveX/Silverlight) in the browser to get access to the client file system.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuantly it is not possible with a standard file upload. The only information that is sent as part of the HTTP POST is the file name, the mime type of the file and the file contents.

If you need the create date or any other info you will need to use a Silverlight or Flash control on the client side.

Answer (score -1):

No.

[* required - at least 15 characters]